# custom jquery selector attributes is not firing in emulator

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, knockout.js

live event is not firing in emulator(mobile,tab), it is working in browser

```
       $("[data-bind]").live("touchstart", function(e) {    

       alert("hi");

      });
```

this is my code...

Comment: Couple of questions: 1) What mobiles are you testing this on? 2) What emulator are you using? and 3) Did you know that `live` is deprecated and you should be using `on`

Comment: i have checked in android mobile and tablet , i tried by using delegate and on, both are not firing even in browser after loading page..but same function is working after run in console

Answer (score 1):

You can apply the selector to the DOM elements only.  You used the [data-bind].

Try like this

```
$("#id").on("touchstart", function (e) {
    var data = $(this).attr('data-bind').val();
    var view = this;
    var url = $(e.currentTarget).attr('title');
    app_router.navigate(url, {
        trigger: true
    });
});
```

Comment: actually i am using knockout..so, i am getting data from viewmodel, i have to use custom selector only

Comment: It's great... shall i know what value comes in [data-bind]?

Comment: First of all you have to return the selector class or id from the viewmodel. for example "#"+someId or "."+someClass then only you have to use this as selector. if u put an alert for databind you will know

Comment: <a data-bind='attr : {"data-url": id()}'> </a>..i want do some functionality by select this data-bind, but its not firing

Comment: do u want to fire an event means use the live function for the tag "a" and get the 'data-bind' value inside the function. look a code above